# ImageMagick v7 conversion of 8bpp images

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, mogrify

On Windows 10, I need to crop and resize whole folders of images.
Following the documentation and some answers here i've built this batch:

```
magick mogrify -path ./cropped -crop 1300x1940+85+130 +repage -resize "800x800^" *.jpg
```

It mostly works, but when a folder has mixed image formats (some are 24bpp, some are 8bpp, grayscale) this batch skips all the 8bpp ones.

How can i change my command so it accepts and modify every image, no matter what?

Note: i used `mogrify` as i understand it is needed to process a whole folder and save the result in another one, but i'm unsure it is necessary.

Comment: JPG does not support 8-bit images only 24-bit. What format are your 8-bit images? You can include other formats in the command *.jpg *.png *.bmp *.tiff etc or all files with just * in place of *.jpg.

Comment: Seems a JPG to me:
https://imgur.com/axleHxL

Comment: My mistake. I was thinking you were asking about 8-bit color. JPG can be grayscale 8-bits.  Can you post an example image that is JPG and fails to process?

Comment: I tested some color and grayscale jpg image (smaller than yours) with a similar command and it works just fine for me.  Is it possible that your crop goes outside some of your images?  What version of IM 7?  I was using IM 7.1.0.44 on Mac OSX Monterey. Works fine for me.